# What is the Correct Microsoft Graph API Permission for Reading Mailbox to specific user only

Tags: api, authentication, outlook, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

Good day!
I just want to ask about microsoft graph Api permission, there's too many options here but my goal is to have the full access ONLY to specific account and read the mail box such as Subject, Email Body, attachment and Sender Email, the system will read the mails from the back end from the specific account only. (like a basic auth)

I'm trying to make system to my org. I don't have the full control in azure portal, so I create API Permission request.

What option need to include in my api permission request?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu7fK.png)

I saw the "Mail.Read" Option
but I think the scope of this option is to access ALL other mail account without signing in. correct me if I'm wrong, but then what I really need is for single account only.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to Graph API is normally done one of two ways:

- [On behalf of user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)
- [As a application (no user)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

The permissions required for the access type are different and are documented for each API endpiont under the Permissions sections.  The on behalf of user access requires "delegated" type permissions and application access require application permissions.

If you use "on behalf of user access" (i.e. you have a user fronting the authentication or you know the username/password) and the correct permissions for the api endponts you are using then you only have access to the data that that user has access too (even if you have permissions like ".all").

If you use "application access" then normally you need higher permissions and you can normally read all user/org data.  In some specific cases you can constrain application access.  Email account access happens to be one. Follow the [Limit Mailbox access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access) instructions to limit a specific application id to a specific set of mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying the delegated access now, one thing I observed in delegated access there's a pop up sign in window appear that I need to put username and password. what i need is to run in background the signing in process, no pop up window. is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you still need to provide the username/password.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet  and https://aka.ms/msal-net-up

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate Mail.Read permission for both Application and Delegated permissions. Application permissions allows the app to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user where as Delegated permissions allows the app to read email in user mailboxes , check the doc for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

In your case you want to check your mail only , then you need to use Delegated permissions , which doesn't required admin conesent

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for enlightening, i'll try delegated user

Comment: one thing I observed in delegated access there's a pop up sign in window appear that I need to put username and password. what i need is to run in background the signing in process, no pop up window. is this possible for delegated?

Comment: Delegated permission need user interaction ,  if you are using graph explorer you need to login the graph explorer once and call the API .

Answer (score 0):

-- goal is to have the full access ONLY to specific account and read the mail box

Can I understand your requirement as, you may want to have a user who is admin role and only this user can query mail information for all other users?
If so, you must have a sign in popup window to let users sign in, then your application can validate the user to check if the signed in user is in admin role to determine whether allowing this user to query mails.

But you also mentioned "to run in background the signing in process, no pop up window", so I'm afraid that you want to allow anyone using your application to query mail on behalf on this specific user. In this scenario, I'm afraid you can using client credential flow directly with the application permission.

Comment: describe your requirement can help design your flow.